# Visualize a simple array of floats in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I really didn't think it was going to be this complicated but I've been looking for a while with no success.
In the data context of my View, I have a simple array of floats. I'm looking for a way to show this array in a vertical way. How can I achieve it?

MY Xaml until now:

```
<Grid Margin="0,-1,-7.8,-16" Background="Gray" RenderTransformOrigin="0.353,0.447">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,14,-313.2,38" Width="296" ItemsSource="{Binding check}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The name of the array is `check`.
The following code is not showing anything.

Comment: "*In the data context of my View, I have a simple array of floats*" - show us the relevant parts of your code please. Also tell us why you think you need a ListView with a GridView instead of a simple ListBox, or an even simpler ItemsControl.

Comment: You need a public property to bind. Check is a bad name for an array. I also notice you have a large margin value there. Don't do that. Use a panel such as a grid with rows and columns to arrange major aspects of layout. Write xaml rather than dragging controls on the designer. As clemens implies, a listbox or itemscontrol is the way to go for just the one column of values.

Comment: @spano: What's a "vertical way"? Do you want to display a list of floats with one column and one value per line?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DisplayMemberBinding´ property to bind to the` float`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding check}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Also make sure that `check` is a *public property*:

```
public float[] check { get; set; } = new float[] { 1, 2.2f, 3, 4, 5.6f };
```

And remove any unnecessary margins that may hide the control:

```
Margin="0,14,-313.2,38"
```

Comment: @spano: Did you try this?